# Php and Html code within echo

Tags: php, magento

I'm writing an if statement in which a button needs to show if the cart is empty. 
For this button I need to get the form key of the product for the `data-url`
So something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>/" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>
```

As mentioned above I need to wrap this button in an if statement, so something like this:

```
 <?php
    $_helper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    if (1 > $_helper->getItemsCount()){
        echo '<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/<?php echo Mage::getSingleton(\'core/session\')->getFormKey(); ?>/" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>';
    }
    else{
        '<p>hello</p>';
    }
 ?>
```

But obviously I can't have php echo within echo. Can anybody point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Comment: Here is where you need to read into concatenation. An example of this would be `<?php echo('string here '.$string); ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't put PHP inside HTML inside PHP.  Since you're already in the context of PHP code, just concatenate the values you want to the output:

```
echo '<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/' . Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() . '" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>';
```

The resulting output is always just a string.  You can simply build that string with whatever values you have.

Comment: Instead of using concationation, there is a good practise to use `spritf` function which makes codes more readeable. So,


```echo sprintf( '<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/%s" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>', Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey());```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use string concatenation:

```
echo '<a href="#" data-url=".../' . Mage::getSingleton(...) . '"' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't open PHP up again. You can terminate the HTML interpretation inside an echo.

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
    $_helper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    if (1 > $_helper->getItemsCount()) {
    echo '<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/'.Mage::getSingleton(\'core/session\')->getFormKey().'/" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>';
    }
    else {
        '<p>hello</p>';
    }
    ?>
```